# What is the best way of saving everything in a Rproj so that you can continue where you left of when you reopen?

Tags: rstudio

I am a relative beginner to RStudio but have finished my first successful project coding prediction algorithms with random forrest algorithms.
I  "internet self- taught" and for that project I used the setwd command that I now realise is impractical as I need to revisit sometimes but also need to do other projects simultaneously.

So my next project I started using Rproj from File -> New Project but when I wanted to go back after a crash I get the message "The object no longer exists" when I want to look at the work I already did.
I guess I didn't save my progress the correct way but I don't understand what the best way is.

-"Save workspace" is advised against as you will not have a clean slate when you open R? Indeed when I open R studio now my first project still pops up automatically.
**Question 1:**
If I save "Save workspace as" in a Rproj will that be exclusively within that Rproj or globally?

-Under file there is also "save" ( that saves an RFile if I understand correctly) and "save all". I guess there is also a bunch of commands that can be used.. So I am confused as to how to make it work like a an excel file would or a project in music software for instance.

Ideally I would like to somehow save my progress, close the project and continue working where I was at when I come back. Preferably without having to redo coding, load libraries, data or similar.
**Question 2:**
How do I save the work/ progress/ data in a R project so that I can come back and continue where I left of or even export to a different machine and continue there?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Maybe check this [RStudio support article](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/200526207-Using-Projects)

Comment: Thank you, still don't understand fully. If I "save workspace" while working to avoid losing all work if computer crashes or restarts somehow, will that be saved to a RData file that is exclusive to that RProj directory? In all other software I use the general rule is to save your work regularly but there are so many different ways

Comment: Personally, I never save the workspace, I prefer starting from a clean session and run my code again. To me, there are not a 100 ways of saving your code: you have an RProj in which you create as many R files as you want and you save them regularly. I don't know what really happens when there is a crash